# Can't run pip3 after upgrade

Tags: pip, python-3.4

I can't run pip3 and easy_install3 after upgrade.
For example command pip3 -V crash with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add
```

I'm using openSUSE 42.1 Leap.
Help, please!